# 'list' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch all the products from the firebase database, but in the json data form.
Here's the structure of my database:

```
products{
  0{
    name:...
    price:...
    }
  1{
    name:..
    price:..
```

and so on. And below is the code I tried:

```
import json
from .models import Product
import pyrebase

def get_products():

   database = firebase_key().database()
   product_list = Product.objects.all()



   r = database.child("products").get().each()
   jsonList = r.json()
   jsonData = jsonList['products']

   data = []

   for products in r:

       productData = {}


       productData['name'] = products.name
       productData['image'] = products.image
       productData['price'] = products.price
       productData['description'] = products.description

       data.append(productData)

   return data
```

I'm new to both django and firebase, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: It should be `products.name`, etc. not `products['name']`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited, thanks. Still getting an error " 'list' object has no attribute 'json' ". Could you please help with that?

Comment: Im guessing that this line: ```r = database.child("products").get().each()``` returns a simple list which doesnt have a ```.json()``` attribute

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin pointed out the `each` does not return a json, but a list. You can check it out on the [pyrebase documentation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each).

Your code should probably look like this:

```
all_products = database.child("products").get()
for product in all_products.each():
    data.append(product.val()) # This works if your fields have the same names.
```

**Edit**

If you still need data as a JSON.

```
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```